# Need to run su command If I am a user with sudo access

Tags: sudo, oracle-linux

I am a user in Oracle Linux server with sudo access. If I run `su` command, system prompts for password. When I input my account password, system gives message `Incorrect password` while I login successfully with the same password.

- Why is it happening?
- Need to execute su or sudo command after login if I have sudo access?
- Need to prefix sudo with every command?

Comment: `su` is not `sudo`

Answer (score 8):

> Why is it happening?

Because you use su with no username, su default switch to root, so you must type root's password correctly.

> Need to execute su or sudo command after login if I have sudo access?

You must use sudo.

> Need to prefix sudo with every command?

Yes, you should type sudo before every command which you want to run with root privilege.

**Updated**

What's different between `su` and `sudo`:

- `su` is used to become another user, you switch to another user in your login session and do anything with switched user privilege. You must know the switched user's password to `su` successfully.
- `sudo` is used to execute a command with another user privilege, specified by policy in `/etc/sudoer` file. You don't have to know another user's password to sudo to work. With `sudo`, you only have another user privilege in temporary time. After this time expired, you must type your password again to `sudo` works.

Comment: He/she can run `sudo su`.

Comment: Actually, you can just do `sudo bash` to get a root shell.

Comment: If I run Sudo once just after login, will it not affect every command I execute after that?

Comment: @Gnouc, what is the difference between `sudo` and `su` commands?

Comment: @ursitesion: No, it only affects the command you give it as argument. It doesn't make "you" root, it starts a new root process for the command you use it for.

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that today systems are often set up so that root doesn't have its own password at all, so you only can run commands with root permissions through `sudo`, not through `su` alone (I don't know if this is also the case for Oracle Linux).

Comment: @celtschk: `sudo -s` is enough to get a root shell

Comment: @Ouki: I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: @celtschk so is `sudo -i`. Also "today's systems" basically means Ubuntu. I don't think any other distro disables root by default. Maybe Debian does as well but I'm not sure.

Comment: @terdon: You can do it in any distro by simply not setting the root password (if the installation method you're using allows that).

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I know, I said that I don't know of any non-Debian distro that disables root _by default_. Then again, it's been a while since I installed anything not Debian derived so I might be wrong.